Button in a PropertyGrid missbehaviour
Hello referring to the "Button in a PropertyGrid" post which proposes a solution to add a button to a wxPropertyGrid, I implemented the above code (both under Linux and Windows) and the "graphical" stuff is working properly. Although, from a functional point of view I got strange behaviors.
As on the proposed example, I implemented a PG with 2 buttons. The event handler of Button1 (OnClick1) toggles the value of a boolean variable in the top wxFrame class. The event handler of Button 2 (OnClick2) simply wxLogs the value of such variable. I see the event handlers being called as expected but somehow the second event handler do not sees the changes made by the event handler of Button 1 ... There is something going wrong. Did anybody other observed strange behaviors and may found the problem ?
See below the code to reproduce the observed behaviour
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <wx/window.h>
#include "wx/propgrid/propgrid.h"


class ButtonMover : public wxPGCellRenderer {
public:
   // pointer to the button from the property
   ButtonMover(wxButton* btn) : _btn(btn) {}
protected:
   virtual bool Render(wxDC& dc, const wxRect& rect,
      const wxPropertyGrid* propertyGrid, wxPGProperty* property,
      int column, int item, int flags) const {
      if (column == 0) { // 0 = label, 1 = value
         // instead of actually drawing the cell,
         // move the button to the cell position:
         wxRect rc(rect);
         // calculate the full property width
         rc.SetWidth(propertyGrid->GetClientRect().width - rect.GetX());
         _btn->SetSize(rc); // move button
         _btn->Show(); // initially hidden, show once 'rendered' (moved)
      }
      return true;
   }
private:
   wxButton* _btn;
};

class ButtonProperty : public wxPGProperty {
public:
   // [parent] should be the property grid
   // [func] is the event handler
   // [button] is the button label
   // [label] is the property display name (sort name with autosort)
   // [name] is the internal property name
   ButtonProperty(wxWindow* parent, wxObjectEventFunction func,
      const wxString& button, const wxString& label = wxPG_LABEL,
      const wxString& name = wxPG_LABEL) :
      wxPGProperty(label, name),
      _btn(new wxButton(parent, wxID_ANY, button)),
      _renderer(_btn)
   {
      // connect the handler to the button
      _btn->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, func);
      _btn->Hide(); // when it's off the grid, it's not rendered 
      // (thus not moved properly)
   }
protected:
   virtual wxPGCellRenderer* GetCellRenderer(int column) const {
      return &_renderer; // return button mover
   }
   virtual const wxPGEditor* DoGetEditorClass() const {
      return 0; // not using an editor
   }
private:
   wxButton* _btn; // the button attached to the property
   mutable ButtonMover _renderer; // the button mover //mutable
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
    virtual int  OnExit();
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(wxWindow* parent);

private:
    void OnClick1(wxCommandEvent& evt);
   void OnClick2(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    bool mBool;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
int MyApp::OnExit()
{
    return wxApp::OnExit();
}
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    if (!wxApp::OnInit())
        return false;
    wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame(0L);

    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

MyFrame::MyFrame(wxWindow* parent):
    wxFrame(parent, wxID_ANY, " Application"),
    mBool(false)
{
   wxPropertyGrid* lPG = new wxPropertyGrid(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxPG_SPLITTER_AUTO_CENTER);
   lPG->Append(new ButtonProperty(
      lPG, 
      wxCommandEventHandler(MyFrame::OnClick1),
      wxString("Click me!")));

   lPG->Append(new ButtonProperty(
      lPG,
      wxCommandEventHandler(MyFrame::OnClick2),
      "Edit this!")
   );
    
   // Layout stuff
   lPG->SetMinSize(wxSize(300, 300));
   wxBoxSizer* lGlobalVertSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    lGlobalVertSizer->Add(lPG, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 0);
    SetSizerAndFit(lGlobalVertSizer);

   // Open the log window and redirect messages to it
   wxLogWindow* lLogWindow = new wxLogWindow(this, "Log Messages", false, false);
   lLogWindow->GetFrame()->Move(GetPosition().x + GetSize().x + 10,GetPosition().y);
   lLogWindow->Show();
}
void MyFrame::OnClick1(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
   mBool = !mBool;
    wxLogMessage("OnClick1 mBool status: %s %llx", mBool ? "true": "false", (unsigned long long) & mBool);
}
void MyFrame::OnClick2(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    wxLogMessage("OnClick2 mBool status: %s %llx", mBool ? "true": "false", (unsigned long long) & mBool);
}

OnClick1 and OnClick2 are reporting a different address and value for mBool.
OnClick1 and OnClick2 must report the same mBool value since the member variable is the same....
wxLogMessage reports:
11:46:36: OnClick1 mBool status: false 1ff29be5fa8
11:46:37: OnClick2 mBool status false  1ff29c739b8
11:46:39: OnClick1 mBool status: true 1ff29be5fa8
11:46:40: OnClick2 mBool status false  1ff29c739b8

did you try to debug it?

You can't possibly expect the event handler to know the correct object to call func on if you never pass it to Connect(). You need to explicitly pass MyFrame*  to it for this to work.
Better, make your code type-safe by defining a functor (possibly but not necessarily using a lambda) and use Bind() instead of Connect().

My bad... I just used the code as it has been published without really going trough it ...  substituting the Connect call inside ButtonProperty with a Bind call in the MyFrame constructor solves the issue. Is there any way to move the Bind call inside   ButtonProperty as it was originally for the  Connect call ?

Sure, the simplest way to do it is to just use std::function to pass the functor there (it's not the most efficient, but you probably don't care about it here).
